# CSS How to selector previous element

Tags: html, css

I want to select class AAA if class BBB has class CCC

```css
.AAA+.CCC {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="AAA">Test1</div> <!-- red color -->
<div class="BBB CCC">Test2</div>
<div class="AAA">Test3</div>
<div class="BBB">Test4</div>
```

Comment: Any element with "AAA" class, or siblings of "BBB CCC"?

Comment: `.BBB.CCC + .AAA { color: red; }` ?

Comment: That does next element

Comment: @technophyle only AAA class if next class is CCC

Comment: .AAA:has(+ .BBB.CCC) {
  color: red
}

Comment: FYI, :has is not supported by all browsers please check this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)